# Fluent Validation - Date format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: c#, datetime, fluentvalidation

I have searched and cannot seem to find the answer to this.  I am trying to validate a date of birth which has a property of datetime.

```
RuleFor(c => c.Customer.DateOfBirth).NotEmpty().WithMessage("DOB is required").Must(CanConvertToDateTime());
```

I am trying to use a private function - this may not be the correct way and this is why I'm asking how I can go about this.

```
    private bool CanConvertToDateTime(string val)
    {
        return DateTime.TryParse(val, out _);
    }
```

But I can't get this working.  Can anyone get me moving on this.  My expected rules are

- DOB cannot be null
- DOB is not in the correct format, expected format yyyy-mm-dd

Please note it is the Fluent Validation Rule I'm trying to get working not so much the function.

The class object that I am trying to validate is part of a complex object, but here is a simplified version.  I want my date to be in the format 2021-02-13 and it will fail for any other combinations or if is is simply not a date.

```
     public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You mean it is not a date at all, or it is a date but not that format? What is the actual input?

Comment: The value going in is  date, but I want to make sure the date format is correct I.e. yyyy-mm-dd.  This is 1 field in a complex object.  And it is of type datetime.  So input would look like 2021-02-02.  I want to hook up fluentValidation to validate this input and if it's not in the correct format respond with an error message.  Once again I appreciate your help

Comment: What input are you testing? What do you mean "not working" how do you know it doesn;t work?

Comment: I am testing a date
       public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

Comment: **What is your actual input?** What piece of text are you trying to parse and why do you think the code you have already doesn't work?

Comment: the input is any looks like any date 2011-02-12, 2013-02-12, 2014-02-12

Comment: So why do you think it doesn't work? Do you want it to fail on other formats? Perhaps you need `TryParseExact`

Comment: you are focusing on the function, while I am trying to hook it up to the fluentValidation Library.  I'm expecting to see an answer like this RuleFor(c => c.Customer.DateOfBirth).Must(myfunction).WithMessage("The date is in the wrong format")

Comment: By the time fluentvalidation gets the input, it has already been parsed to a datetime. If it's not a valid date, the model binding will fail. I think the dto type would need to be a string for you to allow FV to perform format validation on it.